# I'm abuse blocked when I want to update my wrong answer

Tags: discussion, edits

I joined Stack Overflow today, after my friend said it is good to learn.

I posted an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56697296/2675154), but as another user says it is wrong.

I have corrected the answer, but I get a message that I can't update, because of an abuse block. There is a red block when I update my answer:

> Your post cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network. We apologize for any inconvenience. See the help center for more.

The page given says that I have spam users on my internet, but I just want to update my wrong answer.

How can I update wrong answer?

update- gimby has edited the answer, but it was later deleted, so no problem now.

Comment: but this is not new question . I just update my old answer. answer is wrong I know the correct answer but I am not able to update answer.

Comment: It's the same problem. Replace "post question" by "edit post", but it's exactly the same issue.

Comment: duplicate box on top says "I will edit to explain how but post not allow me to edit". I am not understand what to do. yivi can you edit my answer with code from link in comments thanks for help

Comment: I want to delete answer but it say answer accepted so can't delete. so frustrating experience. can someone please help.

Comment: Hello there, Its okay. Your answer helped the asker and even got an upvote, there’s no need to panic. Now you should refer to the thread @yivi linked and follow the steps given there to remove the warning.

Comment: The code has been updated as per your request. At this point contain your frustration, read yivi's link. You probably also want to read the [help], as signing up to Stack Overflow on the advice "it is good to learn" may lead to a pretty rough start with many more frustrations. Its good to know what you should and shouldn't do first.

Comment: You joined today, answered two questions and had both accepted so it sounds like you are off to a good start not counting the edit issues.

Comment: ok thank you @gimby. I will read help center and learn what I should do.

Comment: thank you @JoeW. One anser of mine was now removed because question was removed, so I lose all the points. that is ok. I will try to post anser to question that will not be removed.

Comment: one more question. Why myquestion score -3 but duplicate asking same score 27 ?

Comment: @AishSharma: The community rates questions based on its usefulness. If a question has already been asked, then new questions asking (more or less) the same are often less useful.