# Is it necessary to prevent abuse-blocked users from updating answers?

Tags: discussion, edits

I was blocked yesterday from editing my wrong answer because of using a network used by spam users. Hence, I asked the following question on Meta: [I'm abuse blocked when I want to update my wrong answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386301/im-abuse-blocked-when-i-want-to-update-my-wrong-answer).

I read the duplicate post and it mentions that the reason is that the same network was used by users to spam Stack Overflow. I can understand that and it is good that Stack Overflow does this.

However, should Stack Overflow be blocking users from updating answers? The abuse block makes sense, because users should not post spam. But is it needed to block updates as well? I don't understand why we block updates, because spam user won't just post spam and update it. They just keep posting spam everywhere. According to me, Stack Overflow should be blocking just new posts.

Are there any other reasons to block users with spam IP from updating answers?

Comment: Wouldn't make sense to block users for spamming but allow them to edit their older posts to add the spam links there as well.

Comment: are you saying that user first post good answer and then start posting spam @Tom

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Kinda necessary, yeah - a surprisingly common technique for spammers is to post something apparently innocuous and then come back later and edit it into spam. Heck, some of 'em have gotten all fancy and use text-generators trained on existing answers to compose their initial posts.

You seem decent enough, what with coming here to meta to talk to us & all. So I've unblocked your network - it may get blocked again if folks start doing dodgy stuff, but a bit more participation, & you'll be immune to these blocks anyway. So, y'know, just don't do anything dodgy.

Comment: thank you moderator shog9. I work in large company. some people post bad stuff on internet site i think they are the ones who post spam here.

Comment: @AishSharma more likely to be your systems/network rather than the people itself.